# Existence of the transitive closure for sets

Tags: proof-writing, set-theory, relations

How can I prove that the transitive close of an arbitrary set $X$ exists?

> A set $X$ is called *transitive* if $\in$ is transitiv on it. The *transitive closure* $\mathrm{tcl}(X)$ of an arbitrary set $X$ is the smallest transitive set (w.r.t. inclusion) which is a superset of $X$.

I guess it would suffice to show that *any* transitive superset of $X$ exists but I am failing right there.

---

Let me show you my try (note: I know that it fails). Define a function $G(n), n\in \Bbb N$ with

$$G(0)=X,\quad G(n+1)=\bigcup X.$$

This function exists because of the recursive function theorem. From there we can build the set $\mathcal G=\{G(n)\mid n\in \Bbb N\}$ by the axiom of replacement. We then have $\mathrm{tcl}(X)=\bigcup \mathcal G$. This works, because $\in$ is well-founded. Because if $\bigcup \mathcal G$ would not be transitive, this means ther would be an infinite descresing $\in$-sequence (not okay because of axiom of foudnation).

However, as I said, this fails.

- I cannot meaningully define $G$, because I do not realy have any clue what the codomain and domain could be. And I need them to define $G$ as a subset of $\mathrm{Cod}(G)\times \mathrm{Dom}(G)$.
- The part about why $\bigcup\mathcal G$ is transitive is a bit sloppy. But I might be able to make this rigorous. The main problem is the first item.

Comment: You don't need Foundation to prove the existence of transitive closures. Ill-founded sets can be just as transitive as well-founded ones! For example if $x=\{x\}$, then $x$ is both transitive and a strong counterexample to Foundation.

Comment: @Asaf But I guess then usual recursion will not suffice but I need transfinit recursion? I mean because I do not know that $\omega$-many steps down the "$\in$-ladder" will suffice.

Comment: Why? Try and follow the argument, without assuming Foundation, and see where you get stuck.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I like your question, because you found a subtle flaw in the way that people sometimes talk about this theorem.

Let's argue instead like this. We shall use the regularity axiom and argue by $\in$-induction. If there is a set without a transitive closure, then there is an $\in$-minimal such set. So we may assume without loss that every element $a\in X$ has a transitive closure $tc(a)$. By the replacement axiom, therefore, we may form the set $\{X\}\cup\{tc(a)\mid a\in X\}$. The union of this set is transitive and contains $X$ as a subset, and in fact, it is precisely the transitive closure of $X$.

An alternative argument would be to argue like this: $X$ is in some $V_\theta$ in the cumulative hierarchy, and every $V_\theta$ is transitive. So this provides a suitable co-domain for your funtion $G$.

Here is third way to argue. For each natural number $n$, there is a unique sequence of length $n$ that iterates the union operation starting from $X$. This can be proved by induction on $n$, since there cannot be least number $n$ violating this. Thus, by the axiom of replacement, we can take the set of all such sequences. This amounts to having your function $G$, from which one can construct the transitive closure.

Comment: The $\in$-induction argument doesn't quite work, since Regularity only says every nonempty _set_ has an $\in$-minimal element.  The cumulative hierarchy argument also looks circular to me, since I don't know how to prove every set is in some $V_\theta$ without using the existence of transitive closures.

Comment: (In particular, the obvious argument that every set is in some $V_\theta$ by $\in$-induction runs into the same problem that Regularity only applies to sets.  You can fix this by using $\in$-induction restricted to the transitive closure of any given set, but this only works if you already know the transitive closure exists.)

Comment: @EricWofsey He's invoking the contrapositive of $\epsilon$-induction directly, which says, for every formula $\phi (x)$, if we have $\forall x ((\forall y \in x \phi (y)) \rightarrow \phi(x))$ then we have $\forall x \phi (x)$

Comment: @SpooFwen: But $\in$-induction is not an axiom schema in ZFC, so you cannot use it until you've proved it from the axioms.  It can be proved, but the proof is nontrivial and uses the existence of transitive closures (to reduce it to the set-restricted version of $\in$-induction provided by Regularity).

Comment: @EricWofsey You are right (although I regard $\in$-induction as the real axiom, and we use regularity only because with transitive closures it suffices; for example, without infinity, you should include the $\in$-induction scheme for finite set theory). Meanwhile, the other two arguments in my answer seem fine.

Answer (score 6):

You are not using Replacement correctly. What Replacement tells you is that if $\varphi$ can be used to define a function with domain $A$, then $\{(a,\varphi(a))\mid a\in A\}$ is in fact a set, and therefore a function in the semantic sense of the word.

What this tells you is that you don't need to know the codomain, and in fact the domain is easy: $\omega$, that's what recursion tells you.

Indeed, this is one of the few great reasons functions in set theory are just particular sets of ordered pairs, rather than $(f,\operatorname{Dom},\operatorname{Cod})$. If you don't have to carry the domain and codomain with you everywhere you go, you can do things more easily.

So we simply have a function, $F(x)=\bigcup x$, and by the recursion theorem, given any $X$ there is a unique function $G$ such that $G(0)=X$ and $G(n+1)=F(G(n))=\bigcup G(n)$.

As for the proof that $T=\bigcup\cal G$ is transitive: suppose $x\in y\in T$, then there is some $n$ such that $y\in G(n)$ this is by the very definition of $T$ as $\bigcup\{G(n)\mid n\in\omega\}$. But now that means that $x\in G(n+1)$, and therefore $x\in T$ as well.

Finally, as you can see, we did not use Foundation here at all. The well-foundedness used for the recursion theorem is that of $\omega$, which is immediate from it being an ordinal. (Recall that without Foundation ordinals are those transitive sets which are well-ordered by $\in$, and not just "transitive set of transitive sets", this equivalence does in fact use Foundation.)

Comment: This proof is the same as my third proof.

Comment: Yes, the idea is the same.